# FMDB ERROR 1: no such table

Tags: iphone, fmdb

I've encountered a strange problem. I just added a test database to my iPhone project, called "pharmacies.sqlite3". I've copied that file into the SUPPORTING FILES folder in my iPhone project.

But even though, I copied my custom db file into the documents folder on the iPhone, I get a message, that the table I am looking for does not exist. Even though it is available. I refactored my code a little bit:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

// FMDB

self.databaseName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"pharmacies.sqlite3"];
NSString *documentsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
self.databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseName];

[self createAndCheckDatabase];
[self getPharmacies];


}
```

And here are my helper methods:

```
- (void)createAndCheckDatabase
{
BOOL success;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:self.databasePath];

if (success) {
    return;
}

NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]    stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseName]; 
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:self.databasePath error:nil];
}

- (void)getPharmacies
{
FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:self.databasePath];

[db setLogsErrors:YES];
[db setTraceExecution:YES];

[db open];

FMResultSet *results = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM pharmacies"];

while ([results next]) {
    NSString *name = [results stringForColumn:@"name"];
    NSLog(@"Apotheke: %@", name);
}
[db close];
}
```

But there is still no table found at all.. did I miss anything? there is no error message that the copying would not have worked....

Comment: try connecting to db in the documents directory. Are you sure that opening db in resources folder is a good idea?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it turns out the problem was that the sqlite database did not appear in the Copy Bundle Resources list (under select the project then click on Build Phases), so it was not packaged with the rest of the resources. I am using XCode 6.

I think what happens is that the fmdb open function creates an empty database. When you query it complains that your table is missing because your own database was never copied in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a forward slash in front of the file name, like so:

```
NSString *finalDatabasePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectory,@"/pharmacies.sqlite3"];
```

This fixed a similar problem I was having.

Comment: Wouldn't this create a double-slash ?? It's output would be XXX//pharmacies.sqlite3 ... this doesn't seem right.

Comment: Here is solution for swift that worked for me. Just adding a slash before the name of the database. I will provide a little bit more code for context:         let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let dirPaths =
            NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,
                                                .UserDomainMask, true)
        
        let docsDir = dirPaths[0] as NSString

        
        databasePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(
            "\\firstAscent.db")

Answer (score 0):

I just gave it a try by changing the code to:

```
NSString *finalDatabasePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsDirectory,@"pharmacies.sqlite3"];

FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:finalDatabasePath];
[database open];
```

Now the error message disappears, but a new one arises:
"DB ERROR 1: no such table: pharmacies"

Interesting issue: the table is definitely there... but according to other sources this means FMDB has created a new DB with the name pharmacies, but without any tables. This happens according to the manual, when there is no such table with that name. So... I made that db copy as you can see above... but there seems to be no DB at all in the doc folder...?

Comment: `copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:` you pass the error reference to that method, and the method itself also returns the BOOL which will tell you if the operation was successful. If it wasn't, you can examine the error to see what went wrong and why the db is not in the doc folder.

Comment: I just did that... and guess what happened.... nothing! no error... due to the fact that FMDB creates his "own" db with this name, there is no error.... oooooh my gooood.. that is not possible! I clearly copied the correct database into my bundle. But he does not recognize it........ Can I force using MY db?

Comment: I have a feeling that the problem might be here: `NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]    stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseName]; 
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:self.databasePath error:nil];`. Examine the path if it's correct, if not use `pathForResource:ofType:`. You can also use debuggers to see which code path is taken.

Comment: What do you mean by: pathForResource:ofType:
shall I use that instead of copyItemAtPath? Could you give me an example please?

Comment: I'm talking about how you create your database path. You do it with `[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseName]`, and I suspect it may not give you the correct result, in which case I think you could try `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pharmacies" ofType:@"sqlite3"];`. Generally, you should really put some debuggers in your code and examine the variables, I'm sure the problem is easy to find but you are the only one who can run the code.

Comment: I found the solution! There was an old pharmacies.sqlite3 file in the doc directory! I implemented the code for deleting it first, and copy it then, and now it works fine!! Thank you all!

Comment: You should update your answer accordingly and mark it as correct answer, so that other can benefit from your efforts too. Thanks

Comment: I posted my answer.. the actual reason is like lawicko mentioned.. the correct DB path is not being discovered here.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this issue for hours.. partly due to the fact .. that I do not understand how paths work in mac environment (coming from MS/Visual studio background)..

Lot of sample code on search results do not work either.. not at least in my case.. so the way I solved it is to look closely at my database file path on SQLiteManager header path right on the top..

It turned out to be..
/Users/myname/Desktop/delete_later/Xcode Projects/CustomerDB/CustomerDBTests/supplier.sqlite

I hardcoded in my code as follows:

```
NSString *writableDBPath = @"/Users/myname/Desktop/delete_later/Xcode Projects/CustomerDB/CustomerDBTests/supplier.sqlite";

db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:writableDBPath];
 [db open];
```

This solved the problem for me right away....